# Hard drive/device partition naming convention in Linux

Tags: linux, partition

What is the hard disk drive/device partition naming convention in Linux? For example, `[hd0,0]`, `sd0`, etc. What does it actually mean?

What is the significance of this when i need to install multiple OSes on the same machine?

How can we relate it to windows partitioning (example: `C:\` drive or `D:\` drive)?

Comment: Cross posted to askubuntu.com: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7575/hard-drive-device-partition-naming-convention-in-linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The convention changes depending on what you're looking at; `hd0,0` looks similar to GRUB, while `sd0` is similar to entries in `/dev`, but neither matches what I normally see.

In `/dev`:

- IDE drives start with `hd`, while SATA (and I believe any kind of serial device) start with `sd`
- Drives are lettered starting with `a` in cable order, so `/dev/sda` is the first serial drive, and `/dev/hdb` is the second IDE drive
- Partitions on a drive are numbered starting with 1, so `/dev/sdb1` is the first partition on the second serial drive

GRUB 1 doesn't have the distinction between drive types, it's always of the form `(hdX, Y)`:

- `X` is the number of the drive, starting with 0, so `sda` is `hd0`, `sdb` is `hd1`, etc.
- `Y` is the number of the partition, starting with **0** (not 1 like `/dev`), so `sda1` is `(hd0, 0)`

I believe GRUB 2 uses a different syntax, but I don't know it

---

It's significant when you're installing multiple OSes if you want to put them on separate partitions -- you need to keep track of which OS is where. It's really significant anytime you're dealing with unmounted drives; you need to know that `/` is on `/dev/sda1` and `/home` is on `/dev/sda2` (for example)

As far as I know, Windows disks start from disk 0, and partitions don't have any particular numbering. Drive letters are assigned however you like and not tied to a particular partition

Comment: Grub 2 works like Grub 1 only the number of the partition starts with 1.

Comment: Also one should note, that some IDE drives show up as /dev/sdX, too. This depends on the chipset and its drivers.

Comment: I should point out that on modern systems, the enumeration is *not* cable order but order of autodetection by `udev`. This poses quite a problem, because sometimes the order gets mixed up. This is why you should always mount either by label or by UUID (the first is set by user and the second is guaranteed not to change unless you reformat your partition). You can also influence the enumeration by writing udev rules - you could assign your own names if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

`(hd0,0)` is [**Grub**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) syntax. (Note that these are parentheses, not square brackets.) Grub is a bootloader, that is, a small program that is launched by your computer's BIOS and whose job is to load the operating system. `hd0` references the first drive detected by the **BIOS**, `hd1` references the second one. The second number is a partition number; Grub 1 starts from 0, while Grub 2 starts from 1. See [“Naming convention” in the Grub manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Naming-convention) if you want more details.

`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc, are the default names of **hard disks** (and other similar storage like flash disks of all kinds, but not CD or tape drives) under **Linux**. The last letter grows in the order in which the disks are detected. You may find `/dev/hda`, `/dev/hdb`, etc, on some Linux distributions. `sd` indicates that the disk driver uses a SCSI interface internally, while `hd` indicates that the driver uses an IDE interface. This is only an internal kernel matter, you can and often do have IDE disks appear as `sd`. The additional number is the **partition number**, starting at 1.

The partitions you're likely to encounter follow the [PC partitioning scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types). A disk has up to four primary partitions, numbered 1 to 4 (or 0 to 3 in Grub 1). It may also have any number of logical partitions, in which case one of the primary partitions cannot contain a filesystem but must instead be an extended partition (a container for the logical partitions). Logical partitions are numbered from 5 on (from 4 in Grub 1).

The names of the device files (e.g. `/dev/sda`) used by Linux are in fact assigned by the [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) program, and can be configured. This is typically useful in advanced situations involving removable media.

Most of the time, you don't need to care about device names. They are referenced in a very small number of places, typically only two: the bootloader configuration (as we've seen, Grub has its own names anyway), and the file `/etc/fstab` which lists the filesystems to mount on boot. (And even `/etc/fstab` does not always reference partitions by names like `/dev/sda1`.) What matters is **mount points**, that is, the location (directory) at which each filesystem is mounted.

Windows uses a completely different naming scheme which is hard to relate to the underlying hardware structure. `c:`, `d:`, etc, are assigned to partitions of a type that Windows recognizes in a particular order (and there are ways to influence this order). [Wikipedia has the details.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_letter#Order_of_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

On my slackware box, /dev/hda is the first hard drive detected.
/dev/hda1 and /dev/hda2 are the first two partitions.

I can use fdisk to see the partitions.

```
/dev/hda1               1         124      995998+  82  Linux swap
/dev/hda2   *         125        1662    12353985   83  Linux
```

On my fedora box, /dev/sda is the first hard drive detected.
/dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 would be the first two partitions.