# Disk space management

Tags: centos

How will I be able to view my entire hard disk space in CentOS?

I have tried `fdisk -l` but it will show me the entire space available but I am not able to judge that where all the space have been located. I have 500G and I can view only 20G in the `fdisk -l` command. Does the other 480G stay hidden? If that is the case, then how to access it?

Comment: Only one question here. To ask about drive naming, open another question. (But preferably search first. Your question may already be answered. See if [Hard drive/device partition naming convention in Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/hard-drive-device-partition-naming-convention-in-linux) answers it.)

Comment: Look at the output of `fdisk -l` and `df`. If you're having trouble interpreting the output, copy-paste it into your question and we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Install `gnome-disk-utility` to view created partitions and free spaces;

And Install `baobab` to see disk consumption of mounted ones.

Comment: thank you very much but i think it is same as fdisk -l .......

Answer (score 1):

`df -h` will show what's up. It should show partitions and sizes of used and available disk space. It's a command-line tool, so you run it in a terminal.